# c++ - Correctly implement WlanSetSecuritySettings for WlanHostedNetwork-functions

Tags: c++, security, networking, wifi

As the title says I'm not quite sure how I correctly implement the [WlanSetSecuritySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706819(v=vs.85).aspx) function in order to get full access from the system for editing the [WlanHostedNetwork from the native wlanapi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx) (-*> as I get an error on some systems, which is saying that I do not have the access and that I require elevation!*). 
In the MSDN doc there is the following manual how to do this - I tried to follow it as far as possible:

> The WlanHostedNetworkForceStart function could fail if Hosted Network
>   state is wlan_hosted_network_unavailable or the caller does not have
>   sufficient privileges. This function to force the start of the Hosted
>   Network can only be called if the user has the appropriate associated
>   privilege. Permissions are stored in a discretionary access control
>   list (DACL) associated with a WLAN_SECURABLE_OBJECT. To call the
>   WlanHostedNetworkForceStart, the client access token of the caller
>   must have elevated privileges exposed by the following enumeration in
>   WLAN_SECURABLE_OBJECT: wlan_secure_hosted_network_elevated_access

and therefore:

> A successful call to the WlanSetSecuritySettings function overrides
>   the default permissions associated with an object. For more
>   information about default permissions, see Native Wifi API
>   Permissions. The following describes the procedure for creating a
>   security descriptor object and parsing it as a string. Call
>   InitializeSecurityDescriptor to create a security descriptor in
>   memory. Call SetSecurityDescriptorOwner to set the owner information
>   for the security descriptor. Call InitializeAcl to create a
>   discretionary access control list (DACL) in memory. Call
>   AddAccessAllowedAce or AddAccessDeniedAce to add access control
>   entries (ACEs) to the DACL. Set the AccessMask parameter to one of the
>   following bitwise OR combinations as appropriate: WLAN_READ_ACCESS
>   WLAN_READ_ACCESS | WLAN_EXECUTE_ACCESS WLAN_READ_ACCESS |
>   WLAN_EXECUTE_ACCESS | WLAN_WRITE_ACCESS Call SetSecurityDescriptorDacl
>   to add the DACL to the security descriptor. Call
>   ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor to convert the
>   descriptor to string. The string returned by
>   ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor can then be used
>   as the strModifiedSDDL parameter value when calling
>   WlanSetSecuritySettings.

So this is my Code first of all (WifiClass is a static class and elevateAccess() is static too) - I did all the steps from the manual above:

```
bool WifiClass::elevateAccess() {

    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR securityDescriptor = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, sizeof(PACL));
    PACL pAcl = (PACL)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, sizeof(PACL));
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    PSID pEveryoneSID = NULL;
    bool bRet, bRes = true;
    DWORD dRet;


    bRet = InitializeSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    if (!bRet)
    {
        bRes = false;
    }

    bRet = IsValidSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor);

    bRet = AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1,
        SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &pEveryoneSID);
    if (!bRet)
    {
        bRes = false;
    }

    bRet = IsValidSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor);

    bRet = SetSecurityDescriptorOwner(securityDescriptor, pEveryoneSID, TRUE);
    if (!bRet)
    {
        bRes = false;
    }

    bRet = IsValidSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor);

    DWORD cbAcl = sizeof(ACL) +
        (sizeof(ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE)) + (GetLengthSid(securityDescriptor) - sizeof(DWORD));
    bRet = InitializeAcl(pAcl, cbAcl, ACL_REVISION);
    if (!bRet)
    {
        bRes = false;
    }

    bRet = IsValidAcl(pAcl);

    bRet = AddAccessAllowedAce(pAcl, ACL_REVISION, WLAN_READ_ACCESS | WLAN_EXECUTE_ACCESS | WLAN_WRITE_ACCESS, securityDescriptor);
    if (!bRet)
    {
        bRes = false;
    }

    bRet = IsValidSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor);

    bRet = SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(securityDescriptor, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
    if (!bRet)
    {
        bRes = false;
    }

    bRet = IsValidSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor);

    LPWSTR* pStringSecurityDescriptor = new LPWSTR;
    bRet = ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor,
        SDDL_REVISION_1,
        DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        pStringSecurityDescriptor,
        NULL
    );
    if (!bRet)
    {
        bRes = false;
    }

    WLAN_SECURABLE_OBJECT wso = wlan_secure_hosted_network_elevated_access;
    dRet = WlanSetSecuritySettings(wlanHandle, wso, (LPCWSTR)pStringSecurityDescriptor);
    if (dRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        bRes = false;
    }

    return bRes;

}
```

**MY PROBLEM:** Everything seems to work, all the isValid-functions always return 'true'. The only part which does not work is

```
ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor,
            SDDL_REVISION_1,
            DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            pStringSecurityDescriptor,
            NULL
        );
```

This part returns `L"D:NO_ACCESS_CONTROL"` in `pStringSecurityDescriptor`. And as expected the next function `WlanSetSecuritySettings(wlanHandle, wso, (LPCWSTR)pStringSecurityDescriptor)` returns `87:INVALID_PARAMETER` as the String is obviously not valid.

**QUESTION:** Did I something wrong following this manual? Do I need something else to initialize or other values? How do I fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because SetSecurityDescriptorDacl() is being passed null for the DACL so it's saying there's a NULL DACL.  It should be passed pAcl instead of NULL, which works for me.